# не обновляются данные в таблице PostgeSQl Java

Tags: java, telegram-bot, spring, telegram

При попытке обновить параметр в БД не происходит изменения, если проверку делать по выводу сообщения, то показывает что меняет параметр, при создании новой записи чекбоксы меняются, все нормально. UPD. case Dislike работает как надо и меняет чекбокс на true/false как надо, ошибка возникает из-за этих строчек

```
userLiked.setState(UserState.LIKED);
    userRepository.save(userLiked);
```

В дебаге ошибок никаких не выдает.

```java
case "like": {
    userLiked = userRepository.findById(user.getViewedUserId())
        .orElse(null);
                                        
    sendMessage(chatId, "Лайк отправлен, ждем ответа");
    
    List<UserLikes> likedList = userLikesRepository.findByLikedAndLiker(userLiked, user);
                                        
    System.out.println("Содержимое likedList:");
    for (UserLikes userLikes : likedList) {
        System.out.println("ID: " + userLikes.getId() + ", Liked: " + userLikes.getLiked() + ", Liker: " + userLikes.getLiker() + ", BooleanLiker: " + userLikes.isBooleanLiker() + ", BooleanLiked: " + userLikes.isBooleanLiked());
    }
    
    if (likedList.isEmpty()) {
        UserLikes newUserLikes = new UserLikes();
                                            
        newUserLikes.setLiked(userLiked);
        newUserLikes.setLiker(user);
        newUserLikes.setBooleanLiker(true);
        newUserLikes.setBooleanLiked(true);
        userLikesRepository.save(newUserLikes);
    } else {
        for (UserLikes userLikes : likedList) {
            // Вывод состояния до изменений
            sendMessage(chatId, "Состояние до изменений:");
            sendMessage(chatId, "BooleanLiked: " + userLikes.isBooleanLiked());
            sendMessage(chatId, "BooleanLiker: " + userLikes.isBooleanLiker());
    
            // Изменение состояния
            userLikes.setBooleanLiked(true);
            userLikes.setBooleanLiker(false);
            // Сохранение обновленной записи в базе данных
            userLikesRepository.save(userLikes);
    
            // Вывод состояния после изменений
            sendMessage(chatId, "Состояние после изменений:");
            sendMessage(chatId, "BooleanLiked: " + userLikes.isBooleanLiked());
            sendMessage(chatId, "BooleanLiker: " + userLikes.isBooleanLiker());
        }
    }
case "dislike":
                                {
                                    userLiked = userRepository.findById(user.getViewedUserId()).orElse(null);
                                    List<UserLikes> likedList = userLikesRepository.findByLikedAndLiker(userLiked, user);
                                    for (UserLikes userLikes : likedList) {
                                        userLikes.setBooleanLiker(true);
                                        userLikesRepository.save(userLikes);
                                    }
                                    showViewKeyboard(chatId);
                                    showOtherUsers(chatId);
                                } break;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может, в транзакции это все выполняется и ее закоммитить надо?